# Checking if a TextBox password field does not have any value or empty in Access

Tags: vba, ms-access, textbox

How will I know if a password textbox field in access is Empty or there's no any value on it?

```
Private Sub cmdLogin_Click()

If IsNull(Me.txtPassword.Value) Or Trim(Me.txtUserName & "") = vbNullString Then
    MsgBox "Username or Password must not be empty.", vbCritical, "Error!"
Else
    MsgBox "welcome"
End If

End Sub
```

The code is what I've tried and even though I tried using `Len(Me.txtPassword & "") = 0`, it still executes the `if` statement. My concern is that if the textbox fields' input mask is a password, it should accept the space(by pressing spacebar) as a text or part of the string. Is there any way I can figure this out?

Comment: So your real question is how to accept a space as a password?

Comment: @CodyG. Yes, you're right, it's a part of it :)

Answer (score 0):

You are specifically not allowing a blank space as a password in your original if statement. This should work:

```
Private Sub cmdLogin_Click()

    If IsNull(Me.txtPassword.Value) Then
        MsgBox "Username or Password must not be empty.", vbCritical, "Error!"
    Else
        MsgBox "welcome"
    End If

End Sub
```

I think it is irrelevant though. Surely what matters is that the password matches the one stored in the database? Personally, I would set the password field in the table to Required = True and AllowZeroLength = False.

In MS Access it is very hard to update a field value to something ending " ". In datasheet view on the table and on forms, when a text field is updated, the value is automatically trimmed. It's quite annoying.